# Unity buttons not working when ARCore recognizes an image from database

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Instantiate an object when ARCore Device recognizes the image from the proper database (working)
- With the object instantiated, place a Canvas object with Buttons on screen directly related to specific instantiated objects. Example: Button 1, when pressed, sets a GameObject inside the instantiated object to true. (not working).

Debugging, I noticed that if I press the button before my device recognizes the image, it does what it was meant to do. But, right after the image has been recognized, the button doesn't do anything. It still reacts to my touch inputs, as the "Selected Color" changes.

Another thing I tried is to instantiate a Canvas object after the image recognition, then press the button to SetActive the object I want to instantiate, and that still doesn't work.

I have an Empty GameObject on my scene with the ARCore Session Script, which is required for the image recognition, and the Augmented Image Example Controller Script, which I use to reference the object I'm trying to instantiate.

Comment: Too little information to go on. Does button get pressed or is input broken? If so, check eventsystem. Otherwise, the script is most certainly not linked to the object right.

Comment: Can you post some code as well?